# How to redirect packets received from one network interface to another network interface?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I am using ubuntu11.10, and I created a tun/tap interface using the following commands

```
openvpn --mktun --dev tun0
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev tun0
route add 10.10.10.1/24 dev tun0
```

I have another interface there

```
eth0 10.80.1.87
```

I wanna redirect packets received from tun0 to eth0. How to do that on top of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

As a complement to the two otherwise good answers, remember that:

- **bridging** work at link layer ("ethernet level") -- and so configuring a bridge between two interfaces is mostly like wiring them through a (virtual) *switch*
- **forwarding** work at network layer ("IP level") -- and so configuring forwarding between two interfaces is like connecting them through a (virtual) *router*

Answer (score 3):

IP forwarding is off by default, as required by the TCPIP standards. 
You turn it on with: 
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

then the forwarding will work. You seem to have added a few lines together in your post, so I cannot determine your networking configuration.

If a packet on tun0 comes in with a destination on eth0, it will now be forwarded. Your Ubuntu machine will work as a router. It will NOT blindly put packets that come in on tun0 onto the ethernet.

So if your IP address on tun0 is 10.10.10.1, then another host, say 10.10.10.45 on tun0 will have to have a gateway of 10.10.10.1 configured (at least for 10.80.1.0/24). Then if it has a packet for say 10.80.1.234, it will first forward it to 10.10.10.1, your Ubuntu machine that will forward it to 10.80.1.234 on the ethernet. Next, THAT machine will reply to 10.10.10.45. It has to be configured to use 10.80.1.87 as the gateway for that host/network. If all that is configured correctly it will work.

An alternative to configuring the correct gateway on the machines on  10.80.1.0/24 would be to enable ip masquerading. Then your ubuntu machine will fake the the FROM address and substitute 10.80.1.87 as the source where 10.10.10.45 used to be.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to [configure bridge between two network interfaces](http://beginlinux.com/sec_train_m/10-traincat/1310-set-up-the-bridge) There is also ubuntu specific manual [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#bridging)

```
$ sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
# vim /etc/network/interfaces:
```

> ```
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto br0
> iface br0 inet static
>         address 192.168.0.10
>         network 192.168.0.0
>         netmask 255.255.255.0
>         broadcast 192.168.0.255
>         gateway 192.168.0.1
>         bridge_ports eth0
>         bridge_fd 9
>         bridge_hello 2
>         bridge_maxage 12
>         bridge_stp off
> ```

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: not necessarily, if the underlying link layer is not ethernet then you can not bridge ethernet with that interface, e.g pt to pt tunnel, in that case you need to route, and im still looking for a solution how to do it?

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: working "here" link https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#bridging

Comment: @northern-bradley thanks for the update, I've updated the link in the answer